# How to use a broadcasted Intent with Jetpack's Compose ComponentActivity with addOnNewIntentListener callback

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, android-jetpack-compose

I am rewriting an app in Kotlin and Jetpack Compose from a React Native app I previously built and I can't seem to pick up an `Intent` being broadcasted from another application handling barcode scanning hardware. I'm using the same [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/darryncampbell/DataWedge-GettingStarted-Samples/blob/master/Kotlin/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) that is filtering these same intents. This was working in the other app I built but I'm now using  a newer SDK and library. The only main difference I see is that this is using `ComponentActivity` and the old app was using [AppCompatActivity (example here)](https://github.com/darryncampbell/DataWedge-GettingStarted-Samples/blob/master/Kotlin/app/src/main/java/com/darryncampbell/dwgettingstartedkotlin/MainActivity.kt)

I added a some logging to see if its being called at all and I see "Setting up intent.." being called but the callback I add using `addOnNewIntentListener` doesn't seem to be called.

Is there something I am missing or needs to be called elsewhere due to LifeCycle activity?

```kotlin
package com.android.composefolderscanner
 import android.annotation.SuppressLint
 import android.content.Intent
 import android.os.Bundle
 import android.util.Log
 import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
 import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
 import androidx.activity.viewModels
 import androidx.compose.runtime.DisposableEffect
 import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
 import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
 import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
 import androidx.core.util.Consumer
 import com.android.composefolderscanner.services.*
 import com.android.composefolderscanner.ui.FolderApp
 import com.android.composefolderscanner.ui.screens.ScanViewModel
 import com.android.composefolderscanner.ui.theme.IgniteFolderScannerTheme
 import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
 import javax.inject.Inject

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {


   private val viewModel: ScanViewModel by viewModels()
   

   @SuppressLint("MissingPermission", "UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      // setContent 
      setContent {
         val resultV = remember { mutableStateOf<Int?>(101) }
         // Use a disposable effect
         DisposableEffect(key1 = resultV.value) {
            Log.i("MainActivity","Setting up intent...")
            val listener = Consumer<Intent>{
               Log.i("MainActivity","Receiving intent...")
               val decodedData = it?.getStringExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.data_string")
               if (decodedData!= null){
                  viewModel.addBarcode(decodedData)
               }
            }
            // Hook callback
            addOnNewIntentListener(listener)
            onDispose {
               Log.i("MainActivity","Removing intents...")
               removeOnNewIntentListener(listener) }
            }
 

         IgniteFolderScannerTheme(useDarkTheme = true, content = {
            FolderApp( )
         })
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: If you override `onNewIntent` manually and add a log message, does that method actually get called at all?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: Then you'll need to compare the entries in your `AndroidManifest.xml` - do you see any difference in how the activity is defined there?

Answer (score 1):

It seems it might be trying to setup the callback too early before context is available. This now works after wraping it in `peekAvailableContext()`

```kotlin
  DisposableEffect(key1 = result.value) {
            peekAvailableContext().let {
               Log.i("MainActivity","Setting up intent...")
               val listener = Consumer<Intent>{
                  Log.i("MainActivity","Receiving intent...")
                  val decodedData = it?.getStringExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.data_string")
                  if (decodedData!= null){
                     viewModel.addBarcode(decodedData)
                  }
               }
               addOnNewIntentListener(listener)
               onDispose {
                  Log.i("MainActivity","Removing intents...")
                  removeOnNewIntentListener(listener)
               }
            }
         }
```